# Sqlite query, compare datetime field with current  date time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite, datetime

In my iPhone app i wanted to query past records. There is a datetime field which named as "task_dateTime" . If used, 
    select task_dateTime from tasks;
Results will look like This,
    Apr 26, 2012 16:32
    Apr 27, 2012 16:38 
    Apr 29, 2012 05:32

How can i query past records. It means i wanted to compare with "task_dateTime" field  with current time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `select task_dateTime from tasks where task_dataTime < CURRENT_TIME`;

Comment: then try select task_dateTime from tasks where task_dataTime <datetime("now")

Comment: or select task_dateTime from tasks where julianday('now') - julianday(task_dateTime) > 0;

Comment: I try with this one                                               select task_dateTime from tasks where task_dateTime > 'Apr 26, 2012 15:22';                                                                            could you help me to format current date with  "Apr 26, 2012 15:22" format

Comment: CURRENT_DATE  and CURRENT_TIME  is keywords of sqlite. and datetime function know "now"is the current time. if you only want to get current time ,you needn't pass the time string from object-c to sqlite. If you mean you want to compare with the certain time like " Apr 26, 2012 16:32" , you must change the date format like "2012-4-26 16:32" and then use like task_dataTime < datetime("2012-4-26 16:32").you can convert the date with nsdateformatter.

Comment: @gage this for hint it works for me NSString *sortSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"delete from table_reminders where reminder_datetime < datetime('%@')",dateString];

Answer (score 1):

For current date :
           NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
    NSString *dateString=[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

[current_date setText:dateString]; //current_date will be the name of your TextBox...

Then compare two strings...

by isequall to string

Comment: Take array of past dates and compare it with present date.....DateFormate will be any thing you want ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're looking for SQLite date logic, where you can put the date logic in a `where` clause. If that's the case, it's worth noting that SQLite doesn't even have a proper date/time data type, as discussed [here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime). Clearly you can use NSDateFormatter to do some conversions of your strings once you get it back to Objective C, but if you want date logic in your SQL `where` clauses, then you really have to conform to SQLite's guidance for the format of Time Strings outlined in [SQLite Date Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

If you want a date in a human readable format, you can use something like "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format. See below for some examples. You can use NSDateFormatter to take this and convert it to a NSDate, from which you can then create date strings in whatever format you want for your UI.

**Update:**

Here is some sample SQL:

```
create table datetest (dt datetime);

insert into datetest values (datetime('now','-1 day'));
insert into datetest values (datetime('now'));
insert into datetest values (datetime('now','+1 day'));

select * from datetest;

select * from datetest where dt < datetime('now');
```

The first select statement will retrieve all three rows. The second returns just two of them.